# Windows Permissions - correct permissions for user documents

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, windows-xp, file-permissions

I am having problems with my user documents folders. We store all our userdocs folders on a windows server 2008 file server. As domain admin I can see the different usersdocs folders, but without changing the owner of the folder I can't see the sub folders and check their permissions etc, and if I change the owner it will cause problems for the user.

Does anyone know a way round this, or how I should set up permission on these folders? My clients are a mix of XP and 7, so whatever the solution I need it to work for both.

Comment: Are you using My Documents Redirection in a GPO?

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify what you mean "userdocs folders"?

It sounds to me like you are talking about roaming profile folders which, by default, do not get admin access. There is a GPO setting "Add the Administrators security group to roaming user profiles" which you can enable in your default domain policy which will resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution is to allow Full Access for the Administrators group on the parent folder, then set up all of the user folders to inherit those permissions, and also grant Full Access to the corresponding user.

It sounds like your user folders are set up so that the user is the owner, and the ACL gives access only to that user. That really only leaves you with two options:

1. Modify the ACL from the security context of the user. This could be a hassle if you have more than a few users.
2. Take ownership of everything, then re-create the ACLs properly. This could be a hassle if you have more than a few users.